# Is で the primary way of introducing a modifying actor into a sentence?

Tags: translation, particle-が, particle-で

I came across this english sentence tonight:

> "The rebel and government groups held talks mediated by the UN."

Which I loosely translated as:

> 反乱の政府はUNで取り締まる会議を開催した。

Is using で the correct way to introduce secondary actors into a sentence or can が be used as well? Such as `反乱の政府はUNが取り締まる会議を開催した` or `ミキさんは神で/が作ったチョコを食べた。`　（Micky ate chocolate made by God).

If が is not right, is there an ambiguity in the first sentence that the talks were being mediated **at** the UN rather than **by** the UN and how would I communicate explicitly that its the organisation of the UN doing the thing without using that particle?

Answer (score 2):

First, I think that you should use 反乱軍代表(者), 反乱代表(者), 反政府軍代表(者), etc. instead of just 反乱.

AのBは pattern is inappropriate for the first part. AとBは or simply inserting a comma between A and B would be correct （反乱代表　と　政府代表）.

UN could also be 国連, the Japanese abbreviation for the UN, or the full Japanese name　国際連合.

As で is more colloquial, you should probably use the more literary にて in this case:

> 反乱代表者と政府代表者はUN（国際連合）の調停/仲裁/仲介にて会談を開催しました。

There is likely already a determined format for saying this in Japanese newspapers. I will yield to more Japanese newspaper savvy commentators on this subject.

Addressing your question about using が, it is allowable with a past indicative verb. For で/にて you would use the passive form:

> 「AさんはBさんが作ったチョコを食べました。」'Mr. A ate chocolate made by Mr. B.'
>
> 「AさんはBさんの秘伝レシピ で/にて 作られたチョコを食べました。」'Mr. A ate chocolate made using Mr. B's secret recipe.'
>
> ---
>
> 反乱代表と政府代表は国連が仲裁した会談を行いました。
>
> 反乱代表と政府代表は国連にて仲裁された会談を行いました。

Comment: `AさんはBさん で/にて 作られたチョコを食べました。` sounds incorrect... (「Bさんで作られたチョコ」 sounds like "chocolate made of/from B-san".) It'd be fine if you said it as 「AさんはBさん**に** (=によって)作られたチョコを食べました。」(chocolate made by B-san), or 「AさんはBさん**の家**で作られたチョコを食べました。」(chocolate made at B-san's)

Comment: 度々すみません。この状態でマシのかな...

Answer (score 0):

> "The rebel and government groups..."

Literal 「反乱軍グループと政府グループ」 might be okay, but I think it can translate to 「反乱軍[側]{がわ}と政府[側]{がわ}」 (*lit.* "rebel side and government side").

> "...held talks..."

I would translate it as 「[会談]{かいだん}を[行]{おこな}った。」

> "... mediated by the UN."

Literally, 「[国連]{こくれん}**に**[仲裁]{ちゅうさい}される～」
 (using passive voice), or 「国連**が**仲裁する～」「国連**の**仲裁する」 ("~~ that the UN mediated") ... but I think it might sound more natural if you said it as 「国連の仲裁で」 ("with the UN's mediation").

Put together:

> "The rebel and government groups held talks mediated by the UN."
>   「反乱軍側と政府側は、国連**に**仲裁される会談を行った。」 <sub>(← literal, using passive)</sub>
>   「反乱軍側と政府側は、国連**が**/**の**仲裁する会談を行った。」 <sub>(← using active)</sub>
>   or 「反乱軍側と政府側は、国連の仲裁で会談を行った。」

---

> Is using で the correct way to introduce secondary actors into a sentence or can が be used as well? Such as 反乱の政府はUNが取り締まる会議を開催した or ミキさんは神で/が作ったチョコを食べた。(Micky ate chocolate made by God).

I would say...

「国連**が**/**の**仲裁する(した)会談」 A talk that the UN mediates (mediated)
「国連**に**(orによって/により)仲裁される(された)会談」 A talk that is (was) mediated by the UN
「神**が**/**の**作った(作る)チョコ」 Chocolate that God made (makes)
「神**に**(orによって/により)作られた(作られる)チョコ」 Chocolate that was (is) made by God

> Is で the primary way of introducing a modifying actor into a sentence?

You'd use が or の to mark the subject in a relative clause.

で as a subject marker is used in limited contexts, eg:

> 当社**で**負担いたします。
>   私どものほう**で**処理させていただきます。

「～～**で**仲裁する会談」「～～**で**作ったチョコ」 would usually be used to say "A talk mediated **at** [place]" "Chocolate made **at** [place] / **from** [ingredients]".